# Convert Thunderbird IMAP mail folder to maildir

Tags: thunderbird, maildir

I currently use `mu4e` with a `maildir` storage format as my email client.

I used to use Thunderbird with an old Outlook based email account for work, using IMAP. In my `.thunderbird` directory tree, I can still find a directory with files called `INBOX`, `Sent-1` etc. where the files appear to be concatenated email messages corresponding to a folder with the corresponding filename. There are also corresponding `.msf` files for (most) of the email files in the same directory.

I want to convert this directory and its files into the `maildir` format, for ease of use. There are a bunch of tools out there for converting `mbox` formats in Thunderbird to `maildir`, including the [perl script `mb2md`](http://batleth.sapienti-sat.org/projects/mb2md/) (which I believe is derived/related to [this Python script](https://www.gerg.ca/hacks/mb2md/)).

I've tried this out and get the error

```
Fatal: Source is not an mbox file or a directory!
```

Are my files in the `mbox` format? They don't have the appropriate extension (i.e. `.mbox`) but as I understood it the format is just a single file per mail folder as I've described above. Or is there something else I have to do?

**EDIT**

This is the command that generates the error. I have not created the `maildir_outlook` directory, but I don't think that's the problem.

```
perl mb2md-3.20.pl -s outlook.office365.com/INBOX -d maildir_outlook
```

For clarity, the `INBOX` file looks like this (after some anonymization):

```
From
Received: from ***.OUTLOOK.COM by ***.OUTLOOK.COM with HTTPS via ***.OUTLOOK.COM with HTTPS via *** Fri, 11 Oct 2019 08:04:18 +000
Received: from *** ...
Received: from *** ...
Authentication-Results: spf=pass (sender IP is ***.***.***.***) 
smpt.mailfrom=*** ...
Received-SPF: Pass ...
Received: from ...
Received: from ...
Received: from ...
...
    MESSAGE BODY
<html xmlns:...
...
```

and this just repeats with all the emails contained in the `INBOX` folder.

The result of `file INBOX` is:

```
INBOX: ASCII text, with very long lines (678), with CRLF line terminators
```

Comment: Adding the copy / paste of the exact command that produced the error might be useful.  It's hard to tell if your files are in mbox format without seeing them, so maybe showing the first number of lines of the file could help (assuming there is no secret info in there); example "head INBOX".  Maybe seeing what the "file" command says about your file could be useful (it's unlikely to identify an mbox file as specifically an mbox file, but it might give some hints); example "file INBOX".

Comment: @DericS Added the command and a summary of the output of `head -n 700` or so, very repetitive headers mostly. The `file` command just says `INBOX` is ASCII text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your outlook.office365.com/INBOX file might be in mbox format.  A [Library of Congress website](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000383.shtml) gives some useful information on a number of mbox formats.  However, I'm going to guess that the issue you are seeing is not related to the format of your INBOX file.

When using the mb2md command, if the source file is not an absolute path, then your **home** directory will be used.  Not your current working directory.

Here's a comment from the mb2md script:

> #  -s source     Directory or file relative to the user's home directory

I suggest that you try using an absolute path with your `-s` option.

If you haven't seen it already, the [following question and answers](https://superuser.com/questions/1169371/how-to-convert-mbox-mail-files-as-found-in-thunderbird-dir-to-maildir) are interesting for the topic at hand.

Comment: Thanks! Should have read the documentation more carefully, and in fact `the relative to user's home directory` applies to `-d` as well. The script does create the directory and the splits INBOX into `cur`, `new`, and `temp` folders with files in just `cur` at the moment. Unfortunately the files don't seem to be just a single message, but a string of messages. Thanks for your the linked post, it looks very useful!